# multiple functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have some variable, or other instance: a='?'.
We have such input:

```
f = a(3112).bas(443).ssad(34)
```

When we type

```
print(f)
```

Output should be:

```
3112a-443bas-34ssad
```

I've tried some ways to solve this and have found information about chaining, but I still have the problem. I can't return class name to the brginning of the string.

This, what I have:

```
class A():       

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(item)    

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print (str(x))

    def b(self, item):
        print (str(item))        
        return self

    def c(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        return self

    def d(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        return self

A(100).b(200).c(300).d(400)
```

My output:

```
100
b
200
c
300
d
400
```

But I couldn't concatenate it in one string.

Comment: Have you tried not printing?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this should support unexpected method names? So `bas` and `ssad` are arbitrary?

Comment: Is this something you need to write using chaining or an underling XY problem? eg: Do you actually want the line demonstrated as Python code, or is it something you need to parse, or is it something you could just do using string concatenation?

Comment: It seems ultimately you're after `'-'.join('{}{}'.format(*el) for el in (('a', 5), ('b', 6), ('c', 35345), ('d', 666)))` in some other way

Answer (score 6):

## Dynamic way

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, integer):
        self._strings = ['{}a'.format(integer)]


    def __getattr__(self, attrname, *args):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self._strings.append('{}{}'.format(args[0], attrname))
            return self

        return wrapper


    def __str__(self):
        return '-'.join(self._strings)


print(A(100).bas(200).ssad(300))
```

Output

```
100a-200bas-300ssad
```

But also

```
 print(A(100).egg(200).bacon(300).SPAM(1000))
```

Output

```
100a-200egg-300bacon-1000SPAM
```

## Static way

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, integer):
        self._strings = ['{}a'.format(integer)]


    def bas(self, integer):
        self._strings.append('{}bas'.format(integer))
        return self

    def ssad(self, integer):
        self._strings.append('{}ssad'.format(integer))
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return '-'.join(self._strings)


print(A(100).b(200).c(300))
```

Output

```
100a-200bas-300ssad
```

[More about __str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: It looks like he needs to handle arbitrary method calls. bas and ssad could be any unexpected method name.

Comment: a couple of seconds apart, but we have the same basic idea.

Comment: removed my answer as this is now clearly much better. The only comment I would have is that it seems your `_dynamic_function` isn't used, and so might be unnecessary here.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can override the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method to define your specific output:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b="", c="", d=""):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c
        self._d = d

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}a-{}b-{}c-{}d'.format( self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d )

    def b(self, item):
        self._b = item
        return self

    def c(self, item):
        self._c = item
        return self

    def d(self, item):
        self._d = item
        return self

f = A(100).b(200).c(300).d(400)
print(f)  # 100a-200b-300c-400d
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I tried it in another way , ie, If you want to take the function name instead of manually giving it you can use `inspect` in python. Try this code :

```
import inspect


class A():
   l = []

   def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print (str(x))
        self.l.append(str(x) + "a")

    def b(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        self.l.append(str(item) + inspect.stack()[0][3])
        return self

    def c(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        self.l.append(str(item) + inspect.stack()[0][3])
        return self

    def d(self, item):
        print (str(item))
        self.l.append(str(item) + inspect.stack()[0][3])
        return self


print("-".join(A(100).b(200).c(300).d(400).l))
```

The o/p is like :

```
'100a-200b-300c-400d'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @vikasdamodar